# Envíar un correo de bienvenida después de registro php+mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

Esto realmente es algo nuevo para mi, puesto que nunca lo he hecho y es un poco urgente esto...

Tengo un formulario en Html que registra varios campos, solo es para que se registre una persona con datos básicos, nombre, correo, celular, ciudad y así **PERO** sin contraseña porque no la solicito, solo es una especie de formulario de contacto en el que nos dejan datos para contactarlos luego...

La conexión a la DB funciona completamente, sin problemas me registra los datos en la DB y muestra una alerta en Javascript también de agradecimiento mas una redirección a la pagina principal, pero lo que necesito hacer es que, al momento de utilizar el botón de registrarse ademas de envíar los datos a la DB, a ese mismo correo que escriban en el campo de Email, se envíe un correo de bienvenida... algo así como "bienvenid@ a tatatatatatatata" ya tengo el hosting y los datos del smtp, solo que no he logrado hacerlo.

Estuve probando phpmailer pero no creo que lo haya implementado muy bien que digamos... primero lo intente en un registro.php que es la que guarda los datos, y luego en el formulario con scripts php tambien y no funcionó... ojalá puedan ayudarme.

Les dejo el codigo del formulario:

```
<form action="insertar.php" method="post" class="contact100-form validate-form">
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                <input id="name" class="input100" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                <label class="label-input100" for="name">
                    <span class="lnr lnr-user m-b-2"></span>
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                <input id="email" class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo ejemplo@email.com">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                <label class="label-input100" for="email">
                    <span class="lnr lnr-envelope m-b-5"></span>
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                <input id="phone" class="input100" type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Celular 312 3456789" />
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                <label class="label-input100" for="phone">
                    <span class="lnr lnr-smartphone m-b-2"></span>
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                <input id="ciudad" class="input100" type="text" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                <label class="label-input100" for="ciudad">
                    <span class="lnr lnr-apartment"></span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100">
                <input id="notas" class="input100" type="text" name="notas" placeholder="Notas">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                <label class="label-input100" for="notas">
                    <span class="lnr lnr-text-align-left"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" align="center">
            <select name="selectform" required>
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccionar Interés</option>
                    <option value="Distribuidor">Distribuidor</option>
                    <option value="info.Detal">Info. Al Detal </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                <button class="contact100-form-btn" type="submit" name="enviar">
                    Enviar información
                </button>
```

Y esto es la validación:

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");


if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && 
isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['ciudad']) && !empty($_POST['ciudad']) && 
isset($_POST['notas']) && !empty($_POST['notas']) && isset($_POST['selectform']) && !empty($_POST['selectform'])) {

    $connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$db);
    mysqli_query($connect,("INSERT INTO nombre_de_la_db (nombre, correo, celular, ciudad, notas, selectform) VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["phone"]."','".$_POST["ciudad"]."','".$_POST["notas"]."','".$_POST["selectform"]."')"));

            echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Gracias por registrarte!");
        window.location.href="index.php";
        </script>'; 

}else {

    echo "ERROR AL INSERTAR DATOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS!";    //. mysqli_error($connect);

}
```

?>

Alguien puede ayudarme con eso?, básicamente sería algo así "enviar variable del campo correo, y usar esa misma variable para enviar un mail con mensaje de bienvenida"

Es algo bastante básico pero es solo para un evento que vamos a realizar en la empresa en otra ciudad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ocasiones he utlizado con buen resultado el siguiente código.
Es muy simple, pero creo que puede hacer lo que buscas.
Cárgalo después del INSERT a la base de datos y antes del script con el alert.

```
<?php
  $Asunto = "Bienvenido a la web";
  $mensaje = "Mensaje de bienvenida...";
  $para = $_POST['email'];
  $de = "webmaster@ejemplo.com";
  $replyTo="respuesta@ejemplo.com";
  $cc="otraCuenta@ejemplo.com";//otros destinatarios (visibles)
  $Bcc="otraCuenta@ejemplo.com";//otros destinatarios (ocultos)

  // Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
  $cabeceras = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

  //Cabeceras adicionales ('para', 'de' y 'contestar a')
  //Puedes eliminar las que no quieras utilizar, como CC y BCC.
  //Obviamente   necesitarás origen y destino
  $cabeceras .= "To:" . $para . "\r\n";
  $cabeceras .= "From: " . $de . "\r\n";
  $cabeceras .= "Reply To: " . $replyTo . "\r\n";
  $cabeceras .= "Cc: ".$cc."\rn";
  $cabeceras .= "Bcc: ".$Bcc."\r\n";

  // Enviamos el email
  mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

Comment: Hola!, gracias por responder... la verdad parece que funciona ya que con el codigo igualmente me registra las cosas en la DB, sin embargo me muestra un error 500 despues de darle a Submit, y esto funciona aunque no tenga los datos smtp en el script y eso? nunca he hecho lo de envíar un correo de bienvenida así que estoy un poquito perdido... Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: El error 500, es un error muy genérico y podría tratarse de un problema de permisos, entre otras cosas.
He editado la línea de "Reply To", ya que dirigía a una variable mía de otra clase, que si no has cambiado sí que puede dar error, ya que en tu servidor no existe.

"La función mail() es parte de PHP, con lo que no neceistas instalar nada, sin embargo, para enviar mail, PHP necesita un sistema de email instalado y funcionando."
Eso está extraido de <https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp> , por si quieres profundizar más en el tema.

Comment: Ohh la verdad si me interesa profundizar porque nunca había enviado un Mail directamente de bienvenida, y el codigo bueno realmente ya no muestra error, y está registrando datos, entonces falta revisar permisos del correo...aunque voy a esperar un rato... Gracias Javier! 

Esperé unos 20 segundos y funcionó perfecto al recibir el correo en Gmail! Gracias de nuevo!